# What's the difference between Red Hat OpenShift Streams and AMQ Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, openshift, redhat

I am designing an Event-Sourcing architecture with Kafka on Openshift. I have recently seen that Red Hat has a module called Red Hat AMQ Streams in the "Integration boundle" (not free of course).

However I have discovered what red hat call "Openshift Streams" and it looks "free cost". I would like to know the diferences between both services. Thank you!

Comment: RedHat sales team should answer this - https://www.redhat.com/en/contact

Comment: But a salesperson doesnt neccessarily help anyone else with the same question -they may not interact with a sales team - e.g. just the curious people!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both products are based on Kafka and Strimzi.

[Red Hat OpenShift Streams for Kafka](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/cloud-computing/openshift/openshift-streams-for-apache-kafka) is a hosted solution. It's not free cost (although there are free trials for developers).

[AMQ](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/jboss-middleware/amq) Streams is also based on Kafka and Strimzi but is customer hosted and managed. As you point out it's part of the overall integration bundle (so is therefore also going to include other related components like Debezium.) It has a more traditional cost model around number of cores that you use.